# How to update constraints programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, autolayout, uikit

I want to update constraints programmatically in code. I have added them in storyboard controller. I made `IBOutlet` for the constraints and connected them. I added values in `updateViewConstrains()` but it isn't working:

```
func updateViewConstraints() {
    centerYConstraint.constant = 60

    super.updateViewConstraints()
}
```

Comment: Show your code, what specifically doesn't work?

Comment: override func updateViewConstraints()
    {
        centerYConstraint.constant = 60

        super.updateViewConstraints()
    }

Answer (score 8):

create an `IBOutlet` in your `viewController.h` file :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *nameButtonVerticalConstraint;
```

now connect it with the concerned autolayout constraint :

[image]

Now you can simply change the constraint like this :

```
self.nameButtonVerticalConstraint.constant=25;
```

And if you want smoother transitions, you can put it inside an animation block :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 delay:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    self.nameButtonVerticalConstraint.constant=50;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:nil];
```

EDIT : here's an excerpt from [this](https://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/ios-animating-autolayout-constraints/) article

If other constraints will be affected because of the update to the constraint above, the following must also be called:

```
[viewForUpdate setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```

Now, animate yout view by calling `layoutIfNeeded` inside your animation block.

Answer (score 2):

Try `myConstraintOutlet.constant = newValue;`

Answer (score 1):

You can update the `constant` property of the layout constraint.